# Yii Framework 2.0 Console Application Error Unknown Property enableCookieValidation

Tags: php, console-application, yii2

I am learning how to create console application with Yii 2.0. I have downloaded the Yii advanced package 2.0 which already has the default console application in it. I have copied that console application and pasted in my project. In that console application I have a TestController and an actionIndex() method, very basic following the documentation of Yii 2.0. When I run the command within my project:

```
php yii test
```

I've got the following error:

```
 Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Setting unknown property: yii\console\Request::enableCookieValidation'
```

When I run the same command in the downloaded Yii advanced application. It works fine. I don't know what causes the error in my project and where to check it. Does anyone have a clue? If you ask how my console application look like, it is literally copied from the Yii 2.0 advanced application. If I run:

```
php yii migrate
```

I get the same error.

Comment: Show the content of console/config/main.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you having this line in your console application config:

```
'request' => [
   'enableCookieValidation' => ...
],
```

You should delete it because `yii\console\Request` compared to `yii\web\Request` simply doesn't have that property.

Answer (score 0):

Rememeber that in Yii advanced template, there are three settings instances;   common/config is the first instance, after that , many of these properties override